# DokanNet не работает на Win7

Tags: c#, .net, драйвер

Использую [DokanNet](//github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet) и [Dokany](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany) для создания виртуального диска.

Шкурка, которая ничего не делает, на Win10 работает, но на Win7 завершается в течение минуты после запуска с ошибкой. Проверял только на двух компах, поэтому не могу гарантировать, что связано с версией ОС. Возможно, проблема связана с чем-то другим. В свойствах проекта выставлен .net framework 4.5.2.

Стандартный пример `RegistryFS` ведёт себя так же (если поменять его зависимость на версию DokanNet.net4.0). Версия под 4.6 вообще не компилируется.

На всякий случай, вот мой несколько изменённый и подчищенный код:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using DokanNet;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using FileAccess = DokanNet.FileAccess;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PackAllStreams
{

  internal class MyDokanImpl : IDokanOperations
  {
    #region DokanOperations member

    public MyDokanImpl()
    {
    }

    public void Cleanup(string filename, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
    }

    public void CloseFile(string filename, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
    }

    public NtStatus CreateFile(
        string filename,
        FileAccess access,
        FileShare share,
        FileMode mode,
        FileOptions options,
        FileAttributes attributes,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus DeleteDirectory(string filename, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Error;
    }

    public NtStatus DeleteFile(string filename, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Error;
    }

    public NtStatus FlushFileBuffers(
        string filename,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus FindFiles(
        string filename,
        out IList<FileInformation> files,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      files = new List<FileInformation>();
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus GetFileInformation(
        string filename,
        out FileInformation fileinfo,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      fileinfo = new FileInformation { FileName = filename };

      fileinfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory;
      fileinfo.LastAccessTime = DateTime.Now;
      fileinfo.LastWriteTime = null;
      fileinfo.CreationTime = null;

      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus LockFile(
        string filename,
        long offset,
        long length,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus MoveFile(
        string filename,
        string newname,
        bool replace,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Error;
    }

    public NtStatus ReadFile(
        string filename,
        byte[] buffer,
        out int readBytes,
        long offset,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      readBytes = 0;
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus SetEndOfFile(string filename, long length, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus SetAllocationSize(string filename, long length, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus SetFileAttributes(
        string filename,
        FileAttributes attr,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus SetFileTime(
        string filename,
        DateTime? ctime,
        DateTime? atime,
        DateTime? mtime,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus UnlockFile(string filename, long offset, long length, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus Mounted(DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus Unmounted(DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus GetDiskFreeSpace(
        out long freeBytesAvailable,
        out long totalBytes,
        out long totalFreeBytes,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      freeBytesAvailable = 512 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L;
      totalBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L;
      totalFreeBytes = 512 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L;
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus WriteFile(
        string filename,
        byte[] buffer,
        out int writtenBytes,
        long offset,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      writtenBytes = buffer.Length;
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus GetVolumeInformation(out string volumeLabel, out FileSystemFeatures features,
        out string fileSystemName, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      volumeLabel = "MyDokanImpl";
      features = FileSystemFeatures.None;
      fileSystemName = string.Empty;
      return DokanResult.Error;
    }

    public NtStatus GetFileSecurity(string fileName, out FileSystemSecurity security, AccessControlSections sections,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      security = null;
      return DokanResult.Error;
    }

    public NtStatus SetFileSecurity(string filename, FileSystemSecurity security, AccessControlSections sections,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      return DokanResult.Error;
    }

    public NtStatus EnumerateNamedStreams(string filename, IntPtr enumContext, out string streamName,
        out long streamSize, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      streamName = string.Empty;
      streamSize = 0;
      return DokanResult.NotImplemented;
    }

    public NtStatus FindStreams(string filename, out IList<FileInformation> streams, DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      streams = new FileInformation[0];
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    public NtStatus FindFilesWithPattern(string filename, string searchPattern, out IList<FileInformation> files,
        DokanFileInfo info)
    {
      files = new FileInformation[0];
      return DokanResult.Success;
    }

    #endregion DokanOperations member
  }

  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      Directory.CreateDirectory("Output");

      try
      {
        var rfs = new MyDokanImpl();
        rfs.Mount(@"r:\", DokanOptions.DebugMode | DokanOptions.StderrOutput);
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
      }
      catch (DokanException ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Строки, предшествующие завершению с ошибкой (mounted появляется после запуска, потом тишина, потом ошибки про запись):

```
mounted: r:\ -> \Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}
###Create 0003
CreateFile status = 0
###QueryVolumeInfo -001
###GetFileInfo 0003
###Create 0004
CreateFile status = 0
        result =  0
###Create 0004
CreateFile status = 0
        FileStandardInformation
        DispatchQueryInformation result =  0
Dokan Error: CreateFile failed \\.\Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}: 2
Dokan Error: CreateFile failed \\.\Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}: 2
Dokan Error: CreateFile failed \\.\Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}: 2
Dokan Error: CreateFile failed \\.\Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}: 2
Dokan Error: DokanKeepAlive CreateFile failed \\.\Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}: 2
Dokan Error: CreateFile failed \\.\Volume{d6cc17c5-1739-4085-bce7-964f1e9f5de9}: 2

unload
Success
```

Обращаю внимание на строку `Success` - т. е. в приложении исключение не возникало, дик по некой причине был размонтирован.

Как можно исправить эту проблему?